# Sort the generic list and allow two names always to be on top and rest sorted

Tags: c#, .net

private  List nodes = new List();

there is a label field inside ISilverNodeModel class of type string.

suppose the nodes list is:

**Malcolm,
Sym,
Eric,
Sandrea**

I want **malcolm and Sandrea always on top and rest to be sorted.**

I am doing this but it sorts all :

> nodes.Sort((node1, node2) =>
>   node1.Label.
>                                    CompareTo(
>                                    node2.Label));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write your own IComparer, and use that implementation in the Sort method.

Your implementation could then determine that malcolm and sandra are always smaller then any other label.

```
public class MySorter : IComparer<ISilverNodeModelClass>
{
   public int Compare( ISilverNodeModelClass left, ISilverNodeModelClass right )
   {
       if( left.Label.Equals (right.Label) )
           return 0;

       if( left.Label == "malcolm" || left.Label == "sandra" )
          return Int32.MinValue;

       if( right.Label == "malcolm" || right.Label == "sandra" )
           return Int32.MaxValue;

       return Comparer<string>.Default.Compare (left.Label, right.Label);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're on .NET 3.5, there's a nice way to do it using LINQ:

```
    List<string> topLabels = new List<string> { "Malcolm", "Sandrea" };
    nodes = nodes
        .OrderByDescending(node => topLabels.Contains(node.Label))
        .ThenBy(node => node.Label)
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                    nodes.Sort((node1, node2) =>
                        {
                            if (node1.Label.Equals(node2.Label))
                            {
                                return 0;
                            }
                            if (node1.Label == "Favorites" || node1.Label == "Recent")
                                {
                                    return Int32.MinValue;
                                }
                            if (node2.Label == "Favorites" || node2.Label == "Recent")
                            {
                                return Int32.MaxValue;
                            }
                            return node1.Label.CompareTo(node2.Label);
                         });
```